# Sharepoint Excel Services NLB

Tags: sharepoint, excel, service

Can anyone throw light on NLB in Sharepoint Excel Services. Specifically here is my question.

When we open a workbook using sharepoint excel web services we call the OpenWorkbook Method that returns a sessionId. Lets say we have a web farm and we get this session from Server A.

Now I call the GetRange Method using the sessionId. If this request is routed to Server B, will it blow up because Server B did not issue sessionId. If not, how is it managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel's services load balancer works similar to any other sticky sessions load balancer - whenever request gets to load balancer it picks server that this session belongs to based on session ID. Note that this session ID is unrelated other session ids like ASP.Net  Session ID (also serving similar purpose).

Load balancing for Excel services happens betweeh servers that run Excel services, not front end ones (which is likely what you talk about Server A and Server B). Front end services are load balanced by whatever load balancing you have setup for the external IP of the farm - usually simple round robin, as front end servers are stateless.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of answers my question. I have another question though i.e. what about session handling in Excel Web Services. What if the app pool is restarted. Would the application fail because it would not recognize the session id anymore.